# How to create ordered list inside text area using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a text area where I add the number of orderlist item on click of a button.This is my code,

```js
var addListItem = function() {
  if (!this.addListItem.num) {
    this.addListItem.num = 0
  }
  ++this.addListItem.num;
  var text = document.getElementById('editor').value;
  console.log('text', text);
  var exp = '\n' + this.addListItem.num + '.\xa0';
  text = text.concat(exp);
  document.getElementById('editor').value = text;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="addListItem()">NumberList</button>
  <textarea id="editor" col=10 rows=10></textarea>
</div>
```

As I have used a static variable to increment it increments on every click and so if I delete the list and create a new list again it doesn't starts from '1'  and also I couldn't figure out how to update the numbers when a item is added in between.Could anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Comment: The listener needs to parse the content to renumber items. Maybe just split on newline and renumber from 1 each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a more robust solution that handles all sorts of different cases, you can use regular expressions to detect what number you're at in your list.

This solution also allows users to type in their own numbers and the button click WILL STILL WORK!

That's because this solution uses the text area content as the source of truth and doesn't track state on the side.

```js
var addListItem = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('editor').value;
  // regex to match against any new line that has a number and a period
  // and extracts the number. feel free to use regex101.com to understand
  // this in more depth.
  var listNumberRegex = /^[0-9]+(?=\.)/gm;
  var existingNums = [];
  var num;
  // get all the matches
  while ((num = listNumberRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    existingNums.push(num);
  }
  
  // sort the values
  existingNums.sort();

  // use the existing biggest number + 1 or use 1.
 
  var addListItemNum;
  if (existingNums.length > 0) {
    // get last number and add 1
    addListItemNum = parseInt(existingNums[existingNums.length - 1], 10) + 1;
  } else {
    // otherwise if there's nothing, just use 1.
    addListItemNum = 1;
  } 

  var exp = '\n' + addListItemNum + '.\xa0';
  text = text.concat(exp);
  document.getElementById('editor').value = text;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="addListItem()">NumberList</button>
  <textarea id="editor" col=10 rows=10></textarea>
</div>
```

understanding regular expressions is tricky, feel free to view https://regex101.com/r/gyX7oO/1 to get a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: thanks, it works .However I could add items inbetween

Answer (score 0):

- If you delete the list and create a new list again it will start from '1'.
- also, counts from whatever the last number is.

```js
var addListItem = function() {
  if (!this.addListItem.num) {
    this.addListItem.num = 0
  }
  ++this.addListItem.num;
  var text = document.getElementById('editor').value;

  //HERE start new counting if textarea is empty
  if(text.trim() == ''){
      this.addListItem.num = 1;  //restart counting here
  }
 //else check if textarea has previous numbers to proceed counting
 else {
    var lastLine = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf("\n") + 1).trim();
    this.addListItem.num = parseInt(lastLine.slice(0, -1)) + 1; //add 1 to last number
 }

  console.log('text', text);
  var exp = '\n' + this.addListItem.num + '.\xa0';
  text = text.concat(exp);
  document.getElementById('editor').value = text;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="addListItem()">NumberList</button>
  <textarea id="editor" col=10 rows=10></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation as to what and why have you changed

Comment: I do not think this is what OP is looking for

Comment: Deleting the list and creating a new list is working but if i add new item in between it goes to the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- On every click, get the text in textarea and split it be new line.
- Now that you have line items, you need to get last sentence that starts with a numeric value. But user can enter new lines on his own to format text.
- For this, loop on every line and validate it it starts with number followed by `.`.
- If yes, use substring to fetch this number and parse it to int. If no match is found, you can return 0.
- This will ensure the numbering system and you do not need a variable to hold last value.

**Note:** This logic assumes that last value will be the maximum. If you wish to handle that, you can just compare `n` and `parseInt` and assign maximum value

**Sample:**

```js
var addListItem = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('editor').value;
  var exp = '\n' + (getLastNumber(text) + 1) + '.\xa0';
  text = text.concat(exp);
  document.getElementById('editor').value = text;
}

function getLastNumber(str){
  var list = str.split(/[\r\n]/g);
  var n = 0;
  list.forEach(function(s){
    if(/^\d+\./.test(s)){
      n = parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(".")));
    }
  });
  return n;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="addListItem()">NumberList</button>
  <textarea id="editor" col=10 rows=10></textarea>
</div>
```